# can we move encrypted virtual machines from subscription to subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, bitlocker

virtual machine is encrypted with disk encryption for data and OS disks.now i want to continue the encryption by moving the same machine into another subscription. the encryption keys are stored in key vault

Comment: This looks to have some guidance: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8684#issuecomment-400024929

Comment: Thanks mark,
$vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.EncryptionSettings is coming as null

Comment: You need to give the full code and where you are stuck with.

Comment: Any update on your side? Is this helpful?

Comment: there is no direct option need to decrypt and take a snap of it and use in another subscription

Comment: yes, not an option for decryption in Portal. I mean you can disable encryption via the Azure Resource Manager template, PowerShell cmdlets, or the Azure CLI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-overview#decryption-workflow

Answer (score 2):

Virtual disks on Azure VMs are encrypted by using cryptographic keys that are secured in an Azure Key Vault. [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#virtual-machines-limitations) states that

> Virtual Machines with certificate stored in Key Vault can be moved to
>   a new resource group in the same subscription, but **not across
>   subscriptions.**

and

> Key Vault - Key Vaults used for disk encryption can't be moved to
>   resource groups in the same subscription or across subscriptions.

So you need to disable encryption the virtual machine first then moves it and enable encryption again with a new key vault.